# Hbase Master name wrong when referencing from client

Tags: hbase

I'm getting a weird issues when I'm trying to connect to the HBase cluster from the client. The client seems to be getting the concatenated HOSTNAME and IP and is unable to connect to the master. Below is a related section from the log file:

```
12/09/27 13:28:41 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 0 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 1000
java.net.UnknownHostException: **?130062@HOSTNAMEIP**
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.<init>(HBaseClient.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:954)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:816)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:141)
        at $Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:174)
        at org.apache.hado
```

Has anybody faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your /etc/hosts file has a problem